# Object of type int is not iterable

Tags: python, int, iteration

Here is my code:

```
NUM = 3                
A = [1,5,6,2,8,4,3,2,5]
B = []
m = []
check = False
summ=0
n = len(A) / NUM
while check == False: 
    for i in A:
        if A.index(i) >= n:
            B.append(m)
            m = []
            n *= 2
        m.append(i)
    B.append(m)
    for j in B:
        s1=(sum(B[0]))
        s2=(sum(B[1]))
        s3=(sum(B[2]))
    print(B)
    if s1==s2==s3:
        summ=s1
        check = True
    else:
        B = [0] * len(A)
        ilg = len(A)
        B[0]=A[ilg-1]
        for i in range(len(A)-1):
            B[i+1] = A[i]
        for i in range(len(A)):
            A[i]=B[i]
```

What I am trying to do is to split my list into 3 lists and if sum of numbers in those lists are equal print sum out, if not print 'FALSE'.
For example: `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`,
after split: `[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]`
but I am getting an error: 
`s1=[sum(B[0])] TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`
What I am doing wrong?

EDIT: Here what I have more, the part after else should change list from [1,5,6,2,8,4,3,2,5] to [5,1,5,6,2,8,4,3,2] and so on.

Comment: @skrrgwasme B[0] contains list: [1,5,6] and i want to sum 1+5+6. How can i do that then? I'm very new to python. Sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: The code doesn't always do what is intended to; for example `A.index(2)` (the second 2 at on 7th position will return 3), and `A.index(5)` (as in 5 the last element) will return 1.

Comment: Are you sure this is your exact code? I get an infinite loop when I run it.

Comment: @Martin This is not the code that gave you the error, because for me no error is being given...

Comment: @Martin Now, we are talking about the same code.

Comment: @Xenomorph Sorry about that, didn't think that part was important too.

Comment: @Martin I've rolled back this question to the previous revision. See the comment on my answer for why I did that.

Comment: @Martin Take a look at [this Meta Stack Exchange post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/273585) for more information about "chameleon questions" and why they should be avoided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
B[0]=A[ilg-1]
```

You're assigning an integer to `B[0]`, which is not an iterable object. On your second iteration around the loop, you pass `B[0]` to the `sum` function, which attempts to iterate over it, throwing the exception.

Comment: I got it. Now i changed last part. Look my edited question. And also changed list in order for it to have needed numbers for my code to work. But now i get: `s2=(sum(B[1])) IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: Instead of editing this question, please open a new one instead. Your original problem has been solved, so you should accept the answer that you felt helped you the most, and open a new question to address your new issue. Edits to add more information are awesome, but edits that change the question render everyone's answers obsolete. You can always include a link back to this question if it helps provide context, but each question should be complete on their own and address one specific topic.

Answer (score 0):

```
A = [1,5,6,2,8,4,3,2,5]
NUM = 3
n = len(A) / NUM
# here make sure that len(A) is a multiple of NUM
sums = [sum([item for item in A[i * NUM :(i + 1) * NUM]]) for i in range(n)]
# for python versions older than 3 use xrange instead of range.
for i in sums[1:]:
    if i != sums[0]:
        print "FALSE"
        break
else:
    print sums[0]
```

Answer (score -1):

Because you're defining your range incorrectly. You want `i` to be your index, right? So use:

```
for i in np.arange(0, len(B)):
```

after importing `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
```

Edit: Actually no package is needed, just: `for i in range(0, len(B)):`

Comment: It doesn't matter, put whatever variable you want.

Comment: Now i get `ImportError: No module named 'numpy'`.

Comment: That means you don't have this package installed. I will edit my post in a while.

Comment: You can try without numpy using `for i in range(len(B))`  I guess

Comment: There is no need for `numpy`. On Python 2 use `xrange`, on Python 3 use `range`. That's it.

Comment: I was not the one who down voted. On a side note, enforcing a package instead of proposing something built-in is not generally a good thing to do. Especially when a built-in solution is better. That makes me understand why your answer got down voted

Comment: Yes, I simply forgot about the built-in, of course your are right.